# ListView Builder Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

Hi i am new on flutter

I use a ListView.Builder to do something like this:

[image]

I use two widgets one for adress information and one for add new adress item to ListView

I use a callback to inform that add IconButton was pressed but I received an error: **Only static members can be accessed in initializers.** when I call **addItemToList()** method

this is the code:

```
class TestPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestPage2State createState() => _TestPage2State();
}

class _TestPage2State extends State<TestPage2> {
  List<Widget> lwidgets = [
    _Adresses(),
    _HorizontalDivider(),
    _AddElement(() {
      addItemToList();
    })
  ];

  void addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      lwidgets.insert(lwidgets.length - 1, _Adresses());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Contacts'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE5E5EA),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('ADRESS'),
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: lwidgets.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return (lwidgets[index]);
              },
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is te _AddElement Widget:

```
class _AddElement extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onAddItem;

  const _AddElement(this.onAddItem);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 40,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 40,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
              iconSize: 24,
              color: Color(0xFF34C759),
              onPressed: () {
                onAddItem();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I Expect when i tap on green button a new item will be added to ListView like this:

[image]

I will appreciate any help.

Jose Rodriguez

Comment: You cannot call `setState` as the view is not at all rendered when you are creating the list.

Comment: Thanks @SanjaySharma, any suggestion? some url where I can start investigation?

Comment: You can create a loop which inserts in a list and you can return the list of widget that you can call inside build also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some modification based on your code. You did not include the other widget such as _Address so I've added a simple one for demonstration

Instead of appending your addelement widget into the list, you could do a if statement on the list view builder to check if its the last index. On the last index, return a Column consisting of _Address and addelement widget.
Refer to the picture attached and the code.

Let me know if this helps

```
     List<Widget lwidgets = [_Address()]

      void addItemToList() {
        setState(() {
          lwidgets.add(_Address());
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Contacts'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE5E5EA),
          body: Container(child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('ADDRESS'),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  // separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                  //   indent: 0,
                  //   endIndent: 0,


                  // ),
                  itemCount: lwidgets.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    //If its the last index of the lwidget list, append _AddElement under the _addresswidget
                    return index == lwidgets.length - 1
                        ? Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              _Address(),
                              _AddElement(addItemToList),
                            ],
                          )
                        : _Address();
                  },
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),)
        );
      }
    }

    class _AddElement extends StatelessWidget {
      final Function() onAddItem;

      const _AddElement(this.onAddItem);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle),
                  iconSize: 24,
                  color: Color(0xFF34C759),
                  onPressed: () {
                    onAddItem();
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    class _Address extends StatelessWidget {
      const _Address();

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.delete),
              Text('Street Name'),
              Text("postal code"),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[Initiate phase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3Va5.png)

[1 item added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQvEO.png)

[More Item added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/weekv.png)

Comment: Hello, i have tried your solution and the behavior is exactly as expected. Thank You so much! I have only one doubt in this way there will always be an item outside the list. 
in the future I intend to put a save button that goes through the list to get the contact entries. Sorry for asking too much i am new on flutter. Just for the record i found another solution wich is: i use initState to add _AddElement  widget to List<widget>, i will put as an answer too. I would greatly appreciate your opinion

Comment: I would advise not including the save button into the list view. Instead create a column nesting your listview with the save button. It would make it more managable. Also, flutter comes with listview.seperated widget that has a seperator built into the listview builder in case you want to ditch the horizontal divider that u have

Comment: Hi, if the answers helps. Please mark it as answer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do:

I put only one **_Adress** widget to **lwidgets** and use **initState** to put **AddElement** widget

**BEFORE**

```
List<Widget> lwidgets = [
    _Adresses(),
    _HorizontalDivider(),
    _AddElement(() {
      addItemToList();
    })
  ];

  void addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      lwidgets.insert(lwidgets.length - 1, _Adresses());
    });
  }
```

**AFTER**

```
 List<Widget> lwidgets = [
    _Adress(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    lwidgets.insert(lwidgets.length, _AddElement(() => {addItemToList()}));
    super.initState();
  }

  void addItemToList() {
    setState(() {
      lwidgets.insert(lwidgets.length - 1, _Adress());
    });
  }
```

And I Put **_HorizontalDivider()** into **_Adress** widget